# Map results from one table to different columns in another query

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I'm trying to retrieve a set of records from  table that has descriptions on another table in same database.

1. Table 1:
   ColA1 | DescrpA1 
   -- A  - - - - Apple
   -- B  - - - - Orange
    
   -- C  - - - - Banana
   -- D  - - - - Watermelon
2. Table 2:
   ColA2 | Qty1 | ColB2 | Qty2 | 
   --A - - - - -      1 - - - C - - - - 1
   --C - - - - -      1 - - - D - - - - 2
   --B - - - - -      1 - - - A - - - - 1

What I want is a way to map descriptions from Table1 into results of Table2

3. Result:
   ColA2 | Decription | Qty1 | ColB2 | Description | Qty2
   --A - - - - Apple - - - - -1 - - - - C - - -       Banana - - - - 1
   --C - - - - Banana - - - 1 - - - -      D - - - Watermelon - 2
   --B - - - - Orange - - - 1 - - - -       A - -  - Apple - - -  - - - 1

Sorry about the formatting. first time posting a questi

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please will you clarify in your question exactly what you are trying to achieve. Be careful about the words you use - you talk about the "results of Table 2". What do you mean by this? Generally, it's queries that have results, while tables have contents. Is your table really called "Table 1", with columns "ColA1" and "DescripA1"? If I were you, the table would be called something different so I could remember easily what it contained, why don't you share the real names with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to `join` the tables . . . twice:

```
select t2.cola2, t1_a.DescrpA1, t2.colb2, t1_b.DescrpA1
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1_a
     on t2.cola2 = t1_a.cola1 join
     table1 t1_b
     on t2.colb2 = t1_b.cola1;
```

Comment: there are around 7 such columns in total. 7 Joins ? Any other optimized soln?

Comment: 7 such columns? Seems like an odd design.

Comment: @SudarshanKV . . . (1) This is optimized, assuming you have indexes on the columns.  (2) Seven such repeated problems would seem to be an issue with your data model.  You should have seven rows rather than one row with seven such colmns.

Comment: They are actually linked. 
item on col1 has a child item listed in col2. Item on Col2 may have child items on next col and so on.